# Call procedures from different forms

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I am using Lazarus and I have a form called `TForm1` and the unit name's Unit 1. Inside here I have a procedure called `mergeDATfile(a:shortint);` that makes some stuff.

By the way I had to create another form called `TForm2` and inside this I have button (Button1). When it is pressed, it must call `mergeDATfile(a:shortint);` from the 1st form.

[image]

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is to move the `MergeDatFile` function into a common unit which can then be used by both form units.

Comment: What if the method is an instance method?

Comment: I'd say it's highly unlikely in this scenario and in any case, a form instance method to merge two data files is a somewhat dubious design decision.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the method is a method of `TForm1` because it operates on the members of `TForm1`. In which case you would do the following:

1. Expose the method as a public method.
2. Arrange for the `TForm2` instance to have access to an instance of `TForm1`.
3. Call the method on the `TForm1` instance.

If my assumption is incorrect then the method should be moved out of `TForm1` into another unit that can be used by both of your forms.